# Is there a way to force WebAPI to strictly conform to a published interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

The use case that I'm trying to solve is encapsulation of our domain models. For example, we have internal models that are utilized in a back-end processing that we do not want exposed to clients. One of the main reasons for this encapsulation is volatility of change as our domain objects may change more rapid than the "published" client models. Therefore we want to limit the WebApi controllers to only return "published" client models.

To do this we would need to create interfaces outside of the WebApi project that does not have references to the internal models, then utilize those interfaces on the WebAPI controllers, and finally change routing/filtering to verify that routes/methods being accessed are part of the interface.

### Assembly A

```
public class PublishedModel
{
    public int Foo {get; set;}
    public string Bar {get; set;}
}

public interface IPublishedAPI
{
    PublishedModel GetModel(int id);
}
```

### Assembly B

```
public class MyApi : ApiController, IPublishedAPI
{
    public IDomainManager _manager;

    public MyApi(IDomainManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("good/{id}")]
    public PublishedModel Good(int id)
    {
          DomainModel domainModel = _manager.GetDomainModelById(id);
          return new PublishedModel
          {
              Foo = domainModel.Foo,
              Bar = domainModel.Bar,
          }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("bad/{id}")]
    public DomainModel Bad(int id)
    {
          var domainModel = _manager.GetDomainModelById(id);
          return domainModel;
    }
}
```

In the above example, I would like a call to `/bad/1` to return a 404 as it's a route that's not published.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could just limit what is displayed in your class in WebAPI. Only display those fields you want to be "published"

Comment: You could create an action filter that checks to see if the called action is a member of the controller's inherited interface. You could also create a filter that when attributed to methods you don't want exposed return the 404

Comment: @ElenaDBA could you elaborate a little on how to "limit what is displayed"? Are you thinking of adding some attribute to the properties? Thanks!

Comment: @Nkosi a filter was is my best guess on how to accomplish this thank you for validating my thoughts! :) I think you should add that response as an answer so that we all can up-vote it.

Comment: Why does `Bad` exist at all? Are there internal callers?

Comment: Bad exists because the wrong pattern wasn't caught during a pull request. Unfortunately  the out of the box implementation of WebAPI controllers allows the syntax as the internal assemblies are referenced for input/output mapping.

Comment: I mean can you not just remove Bad entirely?

Comment: If it's on the API it's more than likely being consumed. So for future system changes the return value of the Bad method would be a new published model with the necessary information from the internal model copied to the new published model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an action filter that checks to see if the mapped action is a member of the controller's inherited interface.

You could also create a filter that when manually attributed to methods you don't want exposed return the 404 Not Found response.

Answer (score 1):

Create Assembly C which handles all of the interaction with the DomainModel and the construction of PublishedModels.  In Assembly B, remove the reference to the DomainModel assembly.

- Now no one can write code in Assembly B which uses or returns DomainModel objects
- Also no one can write a method in Assembly C which publicly exposes a DomainModel object because Assembly B will also get a compilation error when it tries to use Assembly C.

You now just need to police the project references, which is pretty easy to do visually or via a build check.

Comment: I like Brandon's answer. It enforces the Interface Segregation. "A client should never be forced to implement an interface that it doesn’t use or clients shouldn’t be forced to depend on methods they do not use"(https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design#interface-segregation-principle)